openlayers map.getFeaturesAtPixel returning zero features
I have added a layer group (UTM Projection) and OSM.
Map View projection set to 4326.  Trying to get features at clicking position but, not getting the features at map.onclick event.  Shall I need to assign projection for evt.pixel?
view: new ol.View({  
    projection: "EPSG:4326",        
    zoom: 13,
    maxZoom: 22
    
  
  }),

map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {   
const features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel);
console.log (features.length);
 }); 


I believe you did not add any features.
For example:
layer.getSource().addFeatures();
You can check by doing layer.getSource().getFeatures() to see if there are any features on the map
